# Entity framework navigation property is null

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5

I have 2 simple classes:

```
public class Setting
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SettingId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Name { get; set; }

    public String Value { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public SettingCategory SettingCategory { get; set; }
}

public class SettingCategory
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid SettingCategoryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Value { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Setting> Settings { get; set; }
}
```

When I retrieve a `SettingCategory` from the database the collection Settings is always null.

When I make it a `virtual` then it will say: `The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.`

How can I access my `Settings` list?

The other way around works, if I retrieve a `Setting` from the database the `SettingCategory` property is filled.

This is my initial code-migrations script:

```
CreateTable(
    "dbo.Settings",
    c => new
        {
            SettingId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Name = c.String(nullable: false),
            Value = c.String(),
            SettingCategory_SettingCategoryId = c.Guid(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.SettingId)
    .ForeignKey("dbo.SettingCategories", t => t.SettingCategory_SettingCategoryId, cascadeDelete: true)
    .Index(t => t.SettingCategory_SettingCategoryId);

CreateTable(
    "dbo.SettingCategories",
    c => new
        {
            SettingCategoryId = c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true),
            Value = c.String(nullable: false),
        })
    .PrimaryKey(t => t.SettingCategoryId);
```

And this is the part that gets it from the database:

```
public SettingCategory Get(Guid settingCategoryId)
{
    using (var context = new BackofficeContext())
    {
        return context
            .SettingCategories
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.SettingCategoryId == settingCategoryId);
    }
}
```

**Answer**

I forgot the include in `.SettingCategories`, but I was trying it with a lambda:

```
public SettingCategory Get(Guid settingCategoryId)
{
    using (var context = new BackofficeContext())
    {
        return context
            .SettingCategories
            .Include(s => s.Settings)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.SettingCategoryId == settingCategoryId);
    }
}
```

That doesn't work, but this does:

```
public SettingCategory Get(Guid settingCategoryId)
{
    using (var context = new BackofficeContext())
    {
        return context
            .SettingCategories
            .Include("Settings")
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.SettingCategoryId == settingCategoryId);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is strange. Can you show how are you retrieving SettingCategory?

Comment: Are you sure you have related Settings in your database?

Comment: I am using Code first with migrations so it should make everything right? I added my Initial script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you are disposing of your `BackofficeContext` you cannot use LazyLoading, which is what is happening when you make `Settings` virtual.

You can either increase the lifetime of your `BackofficeContext`, or eager load `Settings`.  You can use eager loading with `Include`.

```
public SettingCategory Get(Guid settingCategoryId)
{
    using (var context = new BackofficeContext())
    {
        return context
            .SettingCategories
            .Include(s => s.Settings)
            .FirstOrDefault(s => s.SettingCategoryId == settingCategoryId);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried that, but the problem is that `s.Settings` is not a recognized expression! `Cannot resolve symbol 'Settings'` That's why I am scratching my head.

Comment: I tried this now: `.Include("Settings")` and that worked, strange that the lambda isn't working.

Comment: Have you added a reference (using) to System.Data.Entity? The strongly-typed Include is highly recommended when doing refactoring.